# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $am^2 + bm + c = x^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $am^2 + bm + c = x^2$ has infinitely many integer solutions $(m,x)$?

My original equation was $12m^2 -12m +1 = x^2$ but I have no idea how to prove this has infinitely many solutions, by elementary methods, as this is for a maths olympiad.

I know that if $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b = 2\sqrt{a}$ then there are only finitely many solutions, but what if $\sqrt{a} \notin \mathbb{Z}$?

Thank you.

Comment: $am^2 + bm + c = x^2\implies (2 a m + b)^2 - a (2 x)^2 = b^2 - 4 a c$, this Pell equation

Comment: What's a Pell equation and why does it have infinite solutions?

Comment: @Roskiller Read up on it, there are many sources on the internet, [like here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/quadratic-diophantine-equations-pells-equation/)

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Why is that a Pell equation? Doesn't $b^2 - 4ac = 1$ have to be true for this to be such an equation?

Comment: @Roskiller in Pell equation RHS can $\neq 1$

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4    https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2    https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

Comment: "I know that if $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b = 2\sqrt{a}$ then there are only finitely many solutions" No, if $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Z},b = 2\sqrt{a}$ and $c=1$, then $am^2+bm+c=(\sqrt a\ m+1)^2$.

Comment: @mathlove I meant that if $\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b = 2 \sqrt{a}$ then $x^2 - (\sqrt{a}   m + 1) = c +1$, which obviously only has finitely many solutions.

Comment: If $\sqrt a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b=2\sqrt a$, then $x^2=am^2+2\sqrt am+c$, not $x^2-(\sqrt am+1)=c+1$. Taking $c=1$, we get $x=\sqrt am+1\in\mathbb Z$ for any $m$. So, there are *infinitely* many solutions.

Comment: @mathlove  I'm confused.. Take the example $a= 4$. Therefore $4m^2 + 4m + c = x^2$. Therefore, $(2m + 1)^2 +c-1 = x^2$ which clearly only has finitely many solutions for each $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. My comment above should read "$= c-1$".

Comment: You wrote "I know that if $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b=2\sqrt a$ then there are only finitely many solutions". This is not correct. You didn't say anything about $c$, so this means that you are wrongly claiming that it has only finitely many solutions **for every** $c$. You are missing the case $c=1$ for which it has infinitely many solutions. Anyway, it is correct that if $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b=2\sqrt a$ and $\color{red}{c\not=1}$, then it has only finitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2=am^2+bm+c$

Solution is,

$(a,b,c)=[(u),(vu-v),(pu-p)^2]$

$(x,m)=[(pu-v+p),(2p-v)]$

For $(u,v,p)=(3,2,7)$

$(a,b,c)=(3,4,196)$

$(x,m)=(26,12)$

$3(12)^2+4(12)+196=(26)^2$

Comment: What if $a=12, b = -12$? Doesn't that imply $v$ is not an integer? Must $u, v, p$ be integers?

Comment: @Roskiiller. The solution given is an identity. You can insert integers & get many nrumerical integers solution. You can even insert rational values & get rational numerical solutions.

Comment: @Roskiller. Re: (12m^2-12m+1=x^2). Take, m=[k (k-2)/(k^2-12)] and x=[(k^2-12k+12)/(k^2-12)]. For k=4, we have (x,m)=(5,2) as solution.